# Recursive method in java to detect a palindrome

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

I´m trying to trace the recursive method that detect if a word is a palindrome or not:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
    if (word.length() == 0 || word.length() == 1) {
        return true; 
    } else if (word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length() - 1)) {
        return isPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length() - 1)); 
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

The word that I've used is: "abba". The first instance of the method takes the else way because the evaluation of the first if condition, so it evaluates the condition in the if else statement obtaining a true as result, then the method returns the running of the method with the word "bb". The recursion runs the method again: the length of "bb" is not 0 or 1, then it takes the else way, and evaluates if the first 'b' is equals to the second 'b', is true, so returns the running of the same method again, but now with a substring that starts in the character in position 1 (beginIndex) 'b' and ends in the character in position 0 (endIndex), but beginIndex is greater than the endIndex and this should Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException ... However the method works. Can somebody explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: I've formatted your code for readability, but in the future I strongly recommend that you do this yourself. Formatting is very important because if your code is not in a standard accepted format, it's not very readable, and if it's not readable, it's not understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second iteration the word is `bb`. Which means the length is `2`.

And your substring is, `word.substring(1, 1)`. Hence it wont (and correctly so) thrown an exception, instead return an empty string.

Comment: Thank you CodeBender, that's it

Answer (score 1):

Adding some `println` can help you in debugging, check [here](http://ideone.com/QYuGnm).

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word){
    System.out.println("Checking "+word+" length: "+word.length());
    if(word.length()==0 || word.length()==1){
        System.out.println("Base Case");
        return true; 
    } else if(word.charAt(0)==word.charAt(word.length()-1)){
        System.out.println("Resursive case substring(1,"+(word.length()-1)+")");
        return isPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length()-1)); 
    }else {
        return false;
    } 
}

Checking abba length: 4
Resursive case substring(1,3)
Checking bb length: 2
Resursive case substring(1,1)
Checking  length: 0
Base Case
```

As you can see on second recursive invocation you have `"bb"` and you are going to check for `substring(1,1)`, documentation states:

> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

`beginIndex` is not > than `endIndex` so no exception is thrown. You can say that the substring starts after character at index 1 and ends after character at index 0 by interpreting

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

```
|      b       |       b      |
                ^
                beginIndex (starts at 1)
              ^
              endIndex - 1 (ends past 0)
```

Comment: Thank you Jack, I'm pleased with the explanation